# adb logcat -c from my macbook pro to a nexus device does not clear the logs

Tags: android

`adb logcat -c` does not [flush](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html) the logcat on Android. It is still showing old entries.

Anyone run into this issue? Cannot seem to find a fix for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your device and Android version you might have run into [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78916): *"adb logcat -c does not clear the buffer when using Android 5.0"*.

The suggested workaround is (look at the end):

```
NOW=$(date +"%m-%d %H:%M:%S.000") ; adb logcat -T "$NOW"
```